# Show that $E(XY) = σ_{XY} + μ_Xμ_Y$?

Tags: variance, mean, covariance, self-study

Let X and Y be two random variables with means $μ_X$ and $μ_Y$ , variances $σ^2_Y$, $σ^2_X$ and covariance $σ_{XY}$ . Show that $E(XY) = σ_{XY} + μ_Xμ_Y$?

I tried the Covariance formula with:

$$Cov(X,Y) = E(X − E(X))(Y − E(Y ))$$
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}{(x − E(X))(y − E(Y ))f(x, y)dxdy}=$$
$$=E(XY ) − E(X)E(Y )$$
$$σ_{XY}=E(XY) - μ_Xμ_Y$$
$$E(XY) = σ_{XY} + μ_Xμ_Y$$

Is this assumption right, because I do not need the two variances in my approach?

Comment: It appears that your signs are munged up since the last two displayed equations are _inconsistent_..  If by $\sigma_{XY}$ you mean $\operatorname{cov}(X,Y)$, then $$\begin{align}\operatorname{cov}(X,Y) &= E[XY]-E[X]E[Y] &= E[XY]-\mu_X\mu_Y\\ E[XY]&= \operatorname{cov}(X,Y) + E[X]E[Y] &=\sigma_{XY}+\mu_X\mu_Y\end{align}$$

Comment: I changed the sings. However, is my approach right, becuause I didn`t use the other two variances?

Comment: Yes, your equations are correct as is your approach. The variances of $X$ and $Y$ do not appear in the covariance formula; you need them when you compute the (Pearson) correlation coefficient $$\rho_{X,Y}=\frac{\text{cov}(X,Y)}{\sqrt{\text{var}(X)\text{var}(Y)}}$$ from the covariance.

Comment: Is there another approach to also use the two variances?

Comment: The role of the variances is hidden. They guarantee that all the relevant expectations exist so that the formal manipulations you've carried out are justified.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have asked essentially the [same question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/326527/15941) on math.SE and I have [answered it there](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/326682/15941), essentially expanding on @cardinal's comment above.